# FB Tagging photo in an app (not FB photo)

Tags: facebook

is it possible to use the FB tagging system for tagging photo not on FB?
I'm developing an app that displays Flickr photos in FB and whish to tag them using the FB tagging.
Curious about that.
Thanks as always,
A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.  If you look at the schema for the [photo_tag](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/) table, it requires a pid (photo id) which is a unique id for a photo in another table.